# Php calculate expiry date from the purchase date in indian format

Tags: php

How to convert this to indian standard time its days-months-years its showing incorrect

```
$purchase_date = "12-29-2018 19:17:04";
$purchase_date_timestamp = strtotime($purchase_date);
$expiry = strtotime("+3 months", $purchase_date_timestamp);
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $expiry);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$purchasedate='2018-12-01';
$no_months=3;

$expDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+3 months", strtotime($purchasedate)));
$expDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+".$no_months." months", strtotime($purchasedate)));
```

**Update**

**To add Days**

```
$expDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+3 days", strtotime($purchasedate)));
$expDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+".$no_days." days", strtotime($purchasedate)));
```

**To add Years**

```
$expDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+3 years", strtotime($purchasedate)));

$expDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+".$no_years." years", strtotime($purchasedate)));
```

Comment: Can we put variable instead of +3 because its not hard coded in my page ?

Comment: yeah sure, you can put variable instead of +3 $expDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$no_days." days", strtotime($purchasedate)));

Comment: Forgot to mention- you need to change Y-m-d to d-m-Y for indan format.

Comment: Ok I will Update it